# authorized.net ambiguity in country names

Tags: html, authorize.net

Hi I am working on a site and integrating authorize.net payment gateway. I am thinking of adding a dropdown for country names, will passing of "United States Of America" as country variable work? Or should I use "US"? Should I use ISO codes for every country? I tried on test developer account but it seems to accept everything I passes to it as correct!

~Ajit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know authorize.net doesn't require country names. A simple way to see if they even validate them would be to run a transaction through the production gateway, pass a nonsense value and see if the transaction still goes through.

If you do standardize to support authorize.net (or for another reason), I'd suggest country codes versus full names. Codes seem to change less often, and also can be useful as identifiers. For example, I have an application which presents data for roughly 200 countries; I have flag icons (multiple sizes for each country) that use a 2 digit country code in their name. Using codes made this fairly easy to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

According to their [AIM Guide](http://www.authorize.net/support/AIM_guide.pdf):

> **x_country**: Optional
>   **Value:** The country of the customer’s billing
>   **Format**: Up to 60 characters (no symbols)